# Npm install failed. I clone others React-router demo(with authority function). but it failed on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, react-router

I clone others React-router demo(with authority function) from this URL https://github.com/wasichris/react-demo

and as you see the Readme document just simply instruct us to do 'npm install' then 'npm start'

But when I came to 'npm install' the following happend:

I hope you guys could help me. Appreciate a lot !!

```
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@12.16.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at getNotFoundError (D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\eien_zheng\\WebstormProjects\\rrrrdemo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN react-demo@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\eien_zheng\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-24T03_12_21_140Z-debug.log

D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo>npm uninstall
up to date in 0.062s

D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo>npm -v
6.13.4

D:\Users\eien_zheng\WebstormProjects\rrrrdemo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing windows build tools,
by running powershell as admin and typing

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

more info here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

Comment: This should be a comment I think.